# Why were the ray-shields in the Naboo Palace turn off and on in a cycle?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

In Star Wars, *Episode 1: The Phantom Menace*, part of the final battle takes place between Darth Maul, Obi-Wan, and Qui-Gon within a reactor room of the Naboo Palace. However, they are separated by a series of what appear to be ray shields, which continually turn on and off. **Why do they do this?** Are the shields on a timer, or did somebody hit a button to make them do that during the beginning of the duel, or is it the Force, or what?

Comment: Why is every industrial facility in the *Star Wars* universe one giant health and safety violation?

Comment: OSHA gonna have a heart attack

Comment: For cinematic/plot reasons, of course